# Webapi posting multiple parameters

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api, fiddler

Iam trying to post multiple parameters to an webapi using fiddler

The call in my webapi is

```
   [HttpPost]
   public object Post(string portfolioAPIKey, DateTime? lastCreativeUTC)
   {
           ......
   }
```

In my webapiconfig

```
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

In fiddler I call the api http://xxxy.com/api/controller/Post use the following content

```
  User-Agent: Fiddler
  Host: xx.com
  Content-Type: application/json
```

When I try accessing it fiddler by passing the following json in the request body

```
       {"portfolioAPIKey":"6B026A0F-F270-4DBF-B84F-CE41F30099A6","lastCreativeUTC":"2014-12-19T12:17:17.8672363Z"}
```

I get 500 internal server error.  Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a class `MyDto` with the following signature:

```
public class MyDto {
    public string PortfolioAPIKey {get;set;}
    public DateTime? LastCreativeUTC {get;set;}
}
```

Modifiy your Post method signature:

```
[HttpPost]
public object Post(MyDto dto)
{
        ......
}
```

Update:

You should not call `/Post` but you should do a `POST` request in fiddler to `http://xxxy.com/api/<controller>` whereas `<controller>` is the name of your controller without the word controller. So if your controller is `MyController`, the correct URL is  http://xxxy.com/api/my

Comment: I just tried that and it still gives me a 500 internal error

Comment: Did you debug it and watch for exceptions?

Comment: Btw you should not call ```/Post``` but you should do a POST in fiddler to ```http://xxxy.com/api/<controller>``` whereas ```<controller>``` is the name of your controller without the word controller. So if your controller is ```MyController```, the correct URL is  http://xxxy.com/api/my

Comment: o MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'MyDto' from content with media type 'application/json'.

Comment: Did you remove the ```JsonMediaTypeFormatter``` from the ```HttpConfiguration```?

Comment: Yes I added  config.Formatters.Clear();
            config.Formatters.Add(new CipherMediaFormatter());

Comment: You need to re-add the ```JsonMediaTypeFormatter```